# Euclid for polynomials

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

I have a question bout euclid polynomials.

If $C(x) =x^4−1$ and $D(x) =x^3+x^2$

How do I find a polynomials $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ such that $A(x)C(x) +B(x)D(x) =x+1$ for all $x$?

Comment: Try long division of polynomials.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division

Comment: You probably mean $=x^2+1$?

Comment: Then $(x^2-1)A(x)+xB(x)=1$ and you can take $A(x)=-1$, $B(x)=x$, for instance.

Comment: It's X+1 as listed.

Comment: Then $D(x)=x^3+1$, otherwise there are no $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Actually I made a typo, please look at the problem again.

Answer (score 0):

By using the expanded  Euclid algorithm one may  get 
$$
{x}^{2} \left( {x}^{3}+{x}^{2} \right) - \left( x+1 \right)  \left( {x
}^{4}-1 \right) =x+1.
$$
Thus $A(x)=-(x+1)$  and $B(x)=x^2.$

Answer (score 0):

This approach is more crude that using the Euclidean algorithm, but it is effective in this case.

Note that both of your two polynomials are divisible by $x+1$. So your problem is equivalent to solving $$A(x)(x^3-x^2+x-1)+B(x)x^2 = 1$$
$A$ must have constant term $-1$ when you consider $x=0$, so this reduces to
$$(x\hat{A}(x)-1)(x^3-x^2+x-1)+B(x)x^2 = 1$$
which after expansion, subtraction of 1, and division by $x$ reduces to 
$$\hat{A}(x)(x^3-x^2+x-1)-x^2+x-1+B(x)x = 0$$
Now $\hat{A}$ must have constant term $-1$:
$$(x\bar{A}(x)-1)(x^3-x^2+x-1)-x^2+x-1+B(x)x = 0$$
and after expansion and division by $x$:
$$\bar{A}(x)(x^3-x^2+x-1)-x^2+B(x) = 0$$
At this point we can solve for $B$ in terms of $\bar{A}$:
$$B(x)=-\bar{A}(x)(x^3-x^2+x-1)+x^2$$

We may as well let $\bar{A}=0$, giving $B(x)=x^2$, $\hat{A}(x)=-1$, and $A(x)=-x-1$.